# does not have a matching glue code

Tags: eclipse, selenium, cucumber

I'm trying to get cucumber to working in Eclipse...

the message is: does not have a matching glue code

I'm following the steps of this website: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cucumber/cucumber_java_testing.htm

but the thing is while you do exactly what the website says, all kinds of things happen that isn't in the description...
f.e. de cucumber.api is created. (the website doesn't say anything about that)
is it better/improved? or unnecessary? (i don't know)

what is wrong with this code, (please help)?

```
package cucumber.api;

import cucumber.junit.Cucumber;

public class CucumberOptions {
    @Cucumber.Options(format = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber"}
    ,glue={"cucumberJava"}
)
}
```

[image]

[image]

also: I can start the runTest.java
the browser FireFox opens
but then nothing happens.... why doesn't it continue?
why does it say: does not have a matching glue, but runs?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tutorial is outdated. This refers to cucumber 1.0.2 and the latest version is 3.0.2. `Cucumber.Options` is deprecated and it is replaced by `CucumberOptions` annotation. Find a more recent one.

Coming to the code, the Cucumber.Options annotations needs to be on the class level like below. Also you are missing the cucumber runner for executing this class.

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@Cucumber.Options(format = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber"}
    ,glue={"cucumberJava"}
)
public class CucumberOptions {

}
```